# Tensorflow multiple scalar multiplication

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a 3d Tensor with `[batch_size,x,y]` and a vector `[batch_size]`.

I want to scalar multiply the i-th matrix `[x,y]` with the i-th entry of the given vector.

Is there a build in function in Tensorflow or do i have to use the `tf.while_loop`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with broadcasting. You need to reshape the vector first.

```
a = tf.constant([[[1,1],[2,2]],[[3,3],[4,4]]])
b = tf.constant([2,3])
c = tf.reshape(b, [-1,1,1])
d = a * c

>>> sess.run(d)
  array([[[ 2,  2],
    [ 4,  4]],

   [[ 9,  9],
    [12, 12]]], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't if there is built in function, but you also don't need to use while loop. You can do basic array manipulation. e.g.:

```
a=tf.random_uniform([3,5,8])
b=tf.random_uniform([3])
c=tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(b, -1),1)
c=tf.tile(c,[1,5,8])
d=tf.multiply(a,c)
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run([a,b,c,d])
```

It should work.